# how to configure code formatter on intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I have to write code in another style. Am I wondering how to configure IntelliJ for this purpose?

It is before code looking:

```
@Override
public void generateTestObjectsInDb(Object... objects) {
    try {
        for (Object obj : objects) {
            DataBaseObjectService.createObjectInDB(obj);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.fatal("Error occured while generating data in product Database.", e);
    }
}
```

And here is how it should look:

```
@Override
public void generateTestObjectsInDb(Object... objects)
{
    try
    {
        for (Object obj : objects)
        {
            DataBaseObjectService.createObjectInDB(obj);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.fatal("Error occured while generating data in product Database.", e);
    }
}
```

How to achive this new code looking after using statndard key bindings ***Ctrl + Alt + L***?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change this in ***settings***

`File` => `Settings` => `Code Style` => `Java` => `Wrapping and Braces` => `Braces Placement`.

Comment: do you know how to make line at editor longer after using `Ctrl + Alt + L`?

Comment: What do you mean by longer? You should ask this into a separate new question.

Comment: sometimes it moves string to next line (method with a lot of parameters). I want to have this at one line for much better readability.

Comment: this is called wrapping. look for it in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

#### IntelliJ IDEA 15

Code Style is under Editor.

**File** > **Settings...** > **Editor** > **Code Style** > **Java** > **Wrapping and Braces** > **Braces Placement** > change "End of line" to "Next line" for "In class declaration", "In method declaration" and "Other" > OK

[image: Braces placement]

On the right side, you will see a live preview.

**Apply the new formatting**

- For the current file:

  - click on the editor area > press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
- For the whole project / a folder

  - click on a folder from the project structure (E.g.: on **src**) > press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>